# Why is my Boostrap navbar scfroll animation not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to animate a navbar that I've made using Bootstrap4 by toggling classes using CSS and Javascript. But the script doesn't seem to work at all no matter what. I am adding the necessary snippets below:

1. **HTML**

   ```
       <!--NAVBAR-->
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark ">
     <a class="navbar-brand ml-4 mt-3px-4" href="#">MR BLUE. </a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>

     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbarSupportedContent">
       <ul class="navbar-nav pr-5 ml-auto mt-3">
         <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         </li>
        ....so on
      <!--NAVBAR-->
   ```

   2.**CSS Classes**

   ```
    .bg-dark{
    background: transparent !important;

   }
   .bg-dark.scrolled{
    transition: 750 ease;
    background: #000000!important;

   }
   ```

   3. **Javascript**

   ```
     <script>
          $(window).scroll(function(){
              $('nav').toggleClass('scrolled',$(this).scrollTop>1080);
          });
      </script>
   ```

The navbar remains transparent. Any help regarding this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

scrollTop is a function. it worked for me when I added the parenthesis

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
           $('nav').toggleClass('scrolled',$(this).scrollTop()>1080);
       });
```

your transition in your css is missing the unit of time. 750 what? seconds? milliseconds?.
use `s` for seconds and `ms` for milliseconds.

Comment: @AvirupDey how big is the page in terms of height? based on your javascript code, you want it to show after scrolling 1080 pixels. can you try changing it to zero as a test? if it still doesn't show. check for any errors on the console. make sure the libraries are loaded properly, that the scrolled  classes is toggled and that any CSS property is no overriding your changes.